# VBA Send email when cell changes using Worksheet_Calculate

Tags: vba, excel

So my code loops through a range of cells and triggers an email on the condition that, in this example, N150 = F150. This works, the email is sent. But what I'm finding difficult is referencing the changed cell in the email body. You can see within the xMailBody variable I have tried cll.Offset(0, -12) so when N150 = F150 I am given the cell value 12 columns to the left which should be B150. Instead I am getting the value of B145 which is correct in that it's the right column but obviously the incorrect row. My target range is N145:N160 so I think it's only referecing the first row in my range. Any help would be greatly appreciated been trying to figure this out for days!

```
Dim target As Range
Dim cll As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Set target = Range("N145:N160")

    For Each cll In target
        If (Range("N150") = Range("F150"))
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook(target)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          cll.Offset(0, -12) & " has reached its target"

    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "email"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Target Reached"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping from N145:N160 but only checking if Range("N150") = Range("F150"). If that check is true it will be true on the first iteration when cll is N145 so the email is sent and the loop exits so no other cll is processed.

```
...
Set target = Range("N145:N160")

For Each cll In target
    If cll = cll.offset(0, -12) then
        'cll is public, no need to pass it or target across
        Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        Exit For
    End If
Next   
...
```

Comment: I have also tried this approach. I found the first cell in the range that meets the condition, for example N150 = F150, works fine. B150 is referenced. But say N151 = F151 as well. The email is triggered twice which is correct, but both times B150 is referenced instead of B150 and B151. In other words any cell beyond the first cell that meets the condition is incorrect.

Comment: I think the loop is being exited as soon as the conidition is met. So if N150 = F150 the email is sent and the loop is exited. Any cells after aren't being covered.

Comment: Yes, the exit for does that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a global variable, pass the value you want in the email as a parameter for your Mail_small_Text_Outlook function.

```
Dim target As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim FoundCell as String
    Set target = Range("N145:N160")

    For Each cll In target
        If (Range("N150") = Range("F150"))
            FoundCell = Cstr(cll.Offset(0, -12).Value2)
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook(FoundCell)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook(FoundCell as String)
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          FoundCell & " has reached its target"

    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "email"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Target Reached"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Now you can watch the value of FoundCell prior to passing it into the function, making your debugging process far easier.